# How can I change some rows in a data frame according to another Data frame data in R?

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames (DF and Mean_glucose). Mean_glucose includes correct glucose data (Gluc) for a specific time (Time_Glucose). So I should replace these correct data with the data in the DF. The code should find same timing and replace glucose value. For this reason I wrote 2 different codes but both them didn't work.

First one:

```
 DF$Gluc[match(Mean_glucose$Time_Glucose, DF$Time_Glucose)] <- Mean_glucose$MnStartGlu
 Error in DF$Gluc[match(Mean_glucose$Time_Glucose, DF$Time_Glucose)] <- Mean_glucose$MnStartGlu : 
 NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

After this error, I used "na.omit" function to exclude all of NA values but it still didn't work.

Second code:

```
 left_join(DF,Mean_glucose,"Time_Glucose") %>%
   mutate(Gluc=coalesce(Gluc.Mean_glucose, Gluc.DF)) %>%
   select(-Gluc.DF,Gluc.Mean_glucose)
 Error in `mutate()`:
   ℹ In argument: `Gluc = coalesce(Gluc.Mean_glucose, Gluc.DF)`.
   Caused by error in `list2()`:
   ! object 'Gluc.Mean_glucose' not found
   Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

What is the wrong?

Comment: Does DF$Mean_glucose contain the correct value for all times?

Comment: DF and Mean_glucose are different data frames. And yes, Mean_glucose$Gluc is always the right one

Answer (score 1):

I am infering from your question that the variable `Time_Glucose` is unique in each data frame and that `DF$Mean_Glucose` contains all the correct values. Essentially, you just need to copy the values from `DF` to `Mean_Glucose`.

If both dataframes are sorted according to their time, you could simply assign the values from `Mean_Glucose$Gluc` to `DF$Gluc`, thus essentially overwriting them. If you want to use the tidyverse, you can also use left_join although using the time as unique identifier. You might have to change the variable names slightly.

```
set.seed(1)

# Set the unique ID in this case time
Time_Glucose <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2013/01/01'), as.POSIXct('2017/05/01'), by="15 mins"), 10)

# Generate some random values
Gluc <- rnorm(10, 0, 1)
Gluc2 <- Gluc
Gluc2[c(2,5)] <- c(0.3, 2)

# Create the MRE dataframes
DF <- data.frame(Time_Glucose, Gluc)
Mean_Glucose <- data.frame(Time_Glucose, Gluc2)

# Solution 1: Simple assignment
DF$Gluc <- Mean_Glucose$Gluc2

# Solution 2: Join the data using left_join from the tidyverse with Time_Glucose as the same value
DF <- left_join(Mean_Glucose, DF, by="Time_Glucose")
```

Comment: I need to copy the Gluc values from Mean_glucose to DF. Also the nrows are different in these 2 dataframes. Your solutions don't work

Comment: Got it, probably best to create a minimum, reproducible example first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It was unclear that the nrows are different in the dataframes.